# Delete features with PyQGIS in a loop

Tags: python, qgis, pyqgis

I have been for months trying unsuccesfully to make a function which can compare a feature with the other ones in a shp layer and if some conditions fulfill, the feature in the loop is deleted. I need it for my final work. The conditions to delete a feature have to be two: if the feature overlay the other one and if it is older than the feature that is in the loop.

```
def superpuestos2(capa, fecha, geom, id):
    listaborrar = []
    
    fecha_feat = fecha
    fechainf_feat = datetime.strptime(fecha_feat, "%d/%m/%Y")
    feat_geom = geom
    
    
    features = capa.getFeatures()
    for f in features:
        
        id_feat = f.attribute('id')
        
        if id != id_feat:
            fecha_f = f.attribute('fecha')
            fechainf_f = datetime.strptime(fecha_f, "%d/%m/%Y")
            
            f_geom = f.geometry()
            inters = f_geom.intersection(feat_geom)
            areageom = feat_geom.area()
            interarea = inters.area()
            fraccion = interarea/areageom
            
            if fraccion > 0.3:
                if fechainf_feat >= fechainf_f:#si la fecha es mas antigua:
                    print("intersecta")#en vez de print que borre el feature de f.
                    listaborrar.append(f.id())
                    
    print(listaborrar)
    capa.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(listaborrar)
```

Comment: what is the problem? Do you get error message? always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: we don't have your data, we can't run your code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question (not in comments)